# how to use 2GP unlocked packaged for existing project

Tags: salesforcedx, package

If I have got some existing code in my org which is not in a package yet. I might create one package in order to retrieve the data into the DX project.

After that I can create an unlocked package and unlocked package version in the scratch org. But since the sandbox/prod orgs already have the classes, objects, fields, it won't allow me to install the new unlocked package back. How should I handle this situation?

Comment: You shouldn't have any issue installing the package even if you already have the metadata in the org. Assuming you have in your package the same metadata version as in your org, the package will just flag the metadata as being part of a package. Do you have any error ?

Comment: @FabienTaillon I haven't tried anything else. For the example in trailhead called Dreamhouse, if I install it twice with two different unlocked package names, I am getting the error: (Property_Favorite__c.Property__c) There is already a Child Relationship named Favorites on Property., Details: Property_Favorite__c.Property__c: There is already a Child Relationship named Favorites on Property. I will try with existing code example later

Comment: Oh yes, one metadata can only be in one Unlocked Package. So if you have already your metadata in the org, but not in an Unlocked Package, you won't have any issue deploying them again in an Unlocked Package. Once this is done, you won't be able to deploy the same metadata again in another Unlocked Package, but you can update it either with regular metadata deploy or a new version of your package.

Comment: @FabienTaillon how does salesforce track the metadata come from which unlocked package? In another word, there are 2 developers Bob and David. Bob puts the metadata in unlocked package x, David puts the same metadata in unlocked package y. Can both run force:source:push sequentially to push to the same sandbox? Thanks.

Comment: If you push them, yes you can, but the workflow is to first create a package and then install it. Via package install you can't have 2 same metadata in 2 packages.